# Python Vectorizing pandas for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, vectorization

I have a question about an interation operation on my Dataframe.
In fact, i would like to compute a "Date" from "Year" and "Day" columns.

My (large) dataframe, called df, has the following structure :

| Year | Day | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1970 | 1 | 1 |
| 1970 | 2 | 1 |
| .... | ... | ... |
| 2022 | 365 | 1230 |

I created a for loop that works but is really not optimized.

```
l=len(df)
list_date=list()

for o in range(0,l):
    day = int(bfc_full.iloc[o]["Day"])
    year = int(bfc_full.iloc[o]["Year"])
    list_date.append(datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(day - 1))
df["Date"]=pd.DataFrame(list_date)
```

I read that vectorization could be a good idea for a large Dataframe but i'm not sure how to do this.

I tried something like this :

```
def doytodate (df, Day, Year):
    df["Date"] = datetime.datetime(Year, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(Day - 1)

doytodate(df,df['Day'].values, df['Year'].values)
```

But it doesn't works

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Could you help me ?

Regards

Comment: like this `pd.to_datetime(df.Year, format='%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(df.Day - 1, unit='D')`?

Comment: @Emma Exactly like this. Thanks you !